# How can I prevent SQL injection with Node.JS?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, express, sql-injection

How could I select a row of MS SQL server database with Node.JS with preventing SQL injection? I use the express framework and the package [`mssql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql).

Here is a part of my code I use now with a possibility to SQL injection written in ES 6.

```js
const express = require('express'),
      app = express(),
      sql = require('mssql'),
      config = require('./config');

let connect = (f, next) => {
    sql.connect(config.database.connectionstring).then(f).catch((err) => {
        next(err);
    });
};

app.get('/locations/get/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    let f = () => {
        new sql.Request().query(`select * from mytable where id = ${req.params.id}`)
                         .then((recordset) => {
            console.dir(recordset);
        }).catch((err) => {
            next(err);
        });
    };

    connect(f, next);
});
```

[image: Cartoon about SQL injection]

Comment: Call a stored procedure rather than having a `SELECT` statement in the code.

Comment: Have you tried using parameters? https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

Comment: No need to use stored procedures. It's not the sproc that prevents SQL Injections, it's the use of parameters. *DON'T* use string formatting or interpolation to create the query, use a parameterized query and pass the parameters separately. That means, no `select * from mytable where id = ${req.params.id}`. It should be `select * from mytable where id = @id` and pass `@id` as a parameter

Comment: From @JavaEvgen: Sry for writing my notice as an answer, can't write comments since my rep is below 50. I would prefer PreparedStatement answer, but if you just need something very simple just do validation on your back-end and make sure that id that you get is integer. Something like this: `if(!isNaN(req.params.id))`
and then do your select

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a PreparedStatement. Here is how you do it from the docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#prepared-statement :

```
var ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(/* [connection] */);
ps.input('id', sql.Int);
ps.prepare('select * from mytable where id = @id', function(err) {
  ps.execute({id: req.params.id}, function(err, recordset) {
    ps.unprepare(function(err) {
        // ... error checks 
    });

    // Handle the recordset
  });
});
```

Remember that each prepared statement means one reserved connection from the pool. Don't forget to unprepare a prepared statement!

You can also create prepared statements in transactions (new sql.PreparedStatement(transaction)), but keep in mind you can't execute other requests in the transaction until you call unprepare.

The docs are written in ES5 but I', sure you can Promisify it :)

Comment: You don't need prepared statements for this. SQL Injection is prevented by the use of parameters.